# databricks-connect cannot load module in udf

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, databricks-connect, pynacl

I'm trying to load `PyNaCl` into a pyspark UDF running on Windows.

```py
from nacl import bindings as c

def verify_signature(msg, keys):
    c.crypto_sign_ed25519ph_update(...)
    ...

verify_signature_udf = udf(lambda x: verify_signature(x, public_keys), BooleanType())

data_signed = data.withColumn(
    "is_signature_valid", verify_signature_udf("state_values")
)
```

`PyNaCl` is installed locally (using `databricks-connect`) but as I understand it is not installed on the executor. Thus I get this:

```
File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 679, in subimport
    __import__(name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nacl'
```

As described in [Python Packaging](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/python_packaging.html) I'm trying to load it like this:

```py
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = "./environment/bin/python"
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(
    "spark.archives",
    "pyspark_venv.tar.gz#environment").getOrCreate()
```

No change, same message.  If I just extract the nacl package from the tar.gz and store it as zip file and load it like this:

```py
spark.sparkContext.addPyFile(path="nacl.zip")
```

it gets loaded but I get this error now:

```
File "/local_disk0/spark-xxx8db3a-5436-4ce8-8ff5-19eaeb4397b4/executor-xxxb7a74-4e1b-40bf-aae2-fc3553155f91/spark-xxx70cb9-482d-42a9-901a-c36f66a42a19/isolatedSparkFiles/0e10cb02-db69-4d63-b7ea-6c2b415fb5d9/nacl.zip/nacl/bindings/crypto_aead.py", line 17, in <module>
    from nacl._sodium import ffi, lib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nacl._sodium'
```

Any ideas?  Would it work with [dbx](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/dbx.html)? Alternatively is there an option to achieve this without an UDF?

**Edit:** In the zip file there are the following sodium components. No additional sodium stuff in the tgz which is not in the zip:

```bash
./nacl/bindings/sodium_core.py
./nacl/bindings/__pycache__/sodium_core.cpython-39.pyc
./nacl/_sodium.pyd
```

**Edit2**: when I move the import into the for loop databricks-connect will run w/o error but the error will be raised upon execution on the executor thus it's also not working like this (was my misunderstanding):

```py
def verify_signature(msg, keys):
    for key in keys:
       # this will prevent databricks-connect to raise a local error
       from nacl import bindings as c  
       c.crypto_sign_ed25519ph_update(...)
       ...

verify_signature_udf = udf(lambda x: verify_signature(x, public_keys), BooleanType())

data_signed = data.withColumn(
    "is_signature_valid", verify_signature_udf(my_keys)("state_values")
)
```

Comment: if you're using databricks, you need to install nacl on the cluster. https://docs.databricks.com/libraries/cluster-libraries.html

Comment: Thanks but PyNaCl is already installed on the cluster.  Note that I'm trying to get this to run with `databricks-connect`.

Comment: Could be a problem with the [installation](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/cryptography-dev/2020-May/000971.html) of PyNaCl?

Comment: Most likely it is a problem w/ the PyNaCl installation.  Just re-installing like proposed in most answers does not work.  The challenge is to have a correct installation inside a UDF.

Comment: I think libsodium is missing in your nacl.zip.

Comment: @Lamanus I updated my message.  The sodium package is there but could be that it is from the wrong platform (not Windows) since this is native stuff.  Will investigate on that.  Thanks for the hint.

Comment: No luck.  This time to be sure I created the nacl.zip under Windows like this: `pip install pynacl`, then I zipped the nacl directory from the virtual env which includes the mentioned sodium files above.  But I get the same error :(

Comment: Also just tried creating the `nacl.zip` on databricks itself and downloaded it. Same problem.